# How does Ofbiz handle sessions?

Tags: session, firefox, selenium, amazon-elb, ofbiz

Sorry for any silly question but I am just about to learn about the web.

I have an application (called OFBench) that uses the Selenium library to simulate user browsing behavior of website. The web site is built on the Ofbiz template (nothing more added). I have 2 EC2 servers on Amazon Web Service that running the ofbiz website template and one client on my laptop generating workload (simulating users on website) for the 2 servers. The browser instance used is firefox.

The 2 servers are sit behind a Elastic Load balancer (ELB) and the ELB is configured with application based session stickiness. When the application simulated a login and then do a "Home" request (clicking the home link on the website) the login state is gone which causes following requests fail. Looks like the ofbiz website does not has session cookie. I am not sure where the problem is, but I need to know how session is handled in ofbiz ? Where does it stored ?

I observed that when I open the home page of the ofbiz website there is a session created (reported by server: xxxxxxx.jvm1 generated) and sessions are generated quite often. Not sure why it is the case. I though only when you login or putting stuff in shopping basket should the session being created.

Thank you very much for answering my question !

Answer (score 1):

Just for the benefits of anyone who having the similar problem. When setting up application based session stickiness with ELB you need to give the name of session that actually generated by your web application, in my case, I saw that there are two kinds of session (JSESSIONID, Ofbiz,Visitor) I used JSESSIONID as session cookieName in ELB and the login state is maintained. Please do correct me if there is anything that might goes wrong. Or anything that I did is happen to work. Many thanks